# Changing file's Build Action does not change .csproj

Tags: tfs

I need to change a file's Build Action property. When I changed it, TFS detected there is a change and I can see the message "something.csproj has been automatically checked out for editing."

[image]

If I do comparison between the .csproj in my local vs the one in source control, there is no change. So when I try to check in the change, it will fail because TFS complains that there is no change.

How do I change a file's Build Action?

This is on TFS (aka Azure DevOps) using TFVC (not git).

Answer (score 0):

After making updates in the local files, make sure you have committed the updates to the local repository. Then you can try to compare the differences between the local and the remote.

Normally, you need to commit the new changes so that these changes can be recorded to the local repository. If not commit, the new changes generally would not be automatically recorded to the repository.

[UPDATE]

Please check with the following things:

- Make sure you have correctly connect to the project on your TFS server.
- Whether the changed file is listed in the '**Pending Changes**' window.
- If the changed file has been listed in the '**Pending Changes**' window, please reference to the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/compare-files?view=azure-devops#compare-files-in-your-workspace-with-the-most-recent-version) to try the comparison between the file in your workspace and the latest version on your TFS server.

In addition, you also can try the [**Difference Command**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/difference-command?view=azure-devops).

Comment: My bad, I should've made it clear in the post. This is on TFS (Azure DevOps) using TFVC. It's not using git.

Comment: Hi @Farid, I have updated my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.